# How to use vieta's formula for a cubic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got the roots for the cubic equation :

A + B + C = -6

ABC = -6

AB+AC+BC = 11

Then i found : A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = 14

Also found + AB^2 + AC^2 + BC^2 = 29 (if i remember :D)

But then i struggle with finding the roots , i mean i can't subsitute as for the quadratic equation ! 
I know i can use cardano's formula , but is there any way i can subsitute and find the roots ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3-(-6)x^2+11x-(-6)=0$$

$$x^3+6x^2+11x+6=0$$

Notice that $x=-1$ is a root.

Hence we are able to reduce the problem to a quadratic problem. Are you able to solve the problem now?

Comment: Yes Siong , I developped the equation , using the roots (-1 ; -2 ; -3 ) , I can find the roots with cardanos formula I guess , but i don't why I can't find it with vieta's formula ...

Comment: If you use substitution, you will end up with .... the cubic equation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! ; Right i ended up with the same equation but then why it works for quadratics equation and not Cubic :/ Sorry i like to ask a lot of why

Comment: It works for quadratic? The last time I tried, I end up with the original quadratic as well. It's ok to ask why, we are here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for which $A,B,C$ are the roots is
$$x^3+6x^2+11x+6=0$$
Note that $x=-1$ is an obvious solution, factor that out and then you are left with a quadratic.

Comment: I know , I developped it XD  Thanks Tho ! , just trying to find the roots in a mathematical way without guesing

Comment: @Ayman if you try to algebraically manipulate Viete's relations you will end up at this cubic only so if you already had the roots then your approach is counterproductive. Viete's relations are in symmetric polynomials so attempts to eliminate any of the variables will lead to this cubic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! ; Right i ended up with the same equation but then why it works for quadratics equation and not Cubic :/ Sorry i like to ask a lot of why

Comment: @Ayman even with quadratic equation if you know $a+b=p$ and $ab=q$, any attempts to isolate $a$ or $b$ will lead to the very quadratic you started with. So there too nothing changes. Perhaps what you have in mind is something different than what you are asking.